# How to get average value from a dict like below?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict like below:

```
dict={idx1:{tokenA: 0.1,
            tokenB: 1.3,
            tokenD: 2.3},
      idx2:{tokenC: 0.9,
            tokenE: 3.4},
      ...
      idxn:{tokenA: 0.3,
            tokenF: 0.4,
            ...
            tokenZ: 7.4}
      }
```

each index may have different tokens/Values, Now I want to get average of each token, simple as below:

```
{tokenA: average_value, tokenB: average_value, ... tokenZ: average_value)
```

any efficient way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haven't tried anything?

Comment: my own solutions is very complicated - I use a lot for clauses. That's why I ask for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d ={'idx1':{'tokenA': 0.1,
            'tokenB': 1.3,
            'tokenD': 2.3},
      'idx2':{'tokenC': 0.9,
            'tokenE': 3.4},
      'idxn':{'tokenA': 0.3,
            'tokenF': 0.4,
            'tokenZ': 7.4}
      }

from collections import Counter

token_sums   = sum((Counter(v       ) for k,v in d.iteritems()), Counter())
token_counts = sum((Counter(v.keys()) for k,v in d.iteritems()), Counter())
token_mean   = {k:token_sums[k]/token_counts[k] for k in token_sums}
print token_mean
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_lists = defaultdict(list)
for key,val in my_dict.items():
    for key2,val2 in val.items():
         my_lists[key2].append(val2)

def average(key_val):
    key,val = key_val
    return (key, sum(val)*1.0/len(val))

print dict(map(average,my_lists))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas

d = {'a': {'t1': 0.1, 
           't2': 0.2}, 
     'b': {'t1': 0.1, 
           't3': 0.2}}
data = pandas.DataFrame(d)

data.T.mean()

=>
t1    0.1
t2    0.2
t3    0.2
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Its an extra dependency, but that's hard to beat in terms of elegance! Does it work with non-string tokens though?

Comment: Also, a dataframe is always a dense datastructure, no? That would have performance implications if the dict datastructure is sparse.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how often you do this kind of stuff. They have implemented [sparse data structures](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html) in pandas as well. I'm not sure about the non-string tokens. I think strings and numbers will be fine, not sure what else would count.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

d ={'idx1':{'tokenA' : 0.1,
            'tokenB': 1.3,
            'tokenD': 2.3},
      'idx2':{'tokenC': 0.9,
            'tokenE': 3.4},
      'idxn':{'tokenA': 0.3,
            'tokenF': 0.4,
            'tokenZ': 7.4}
      }

avg = collections.defaultdict(float)
count = collections.Counter()

for dat in d.itervalues():
    for k,v in dat.iteritems():
        avg[k] += v
        count[k] += 1

for k,v in count.iteritems():
    avg[k] /= count[k]

print avg
```